# woocommerce discount cart withouth using add_fee method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, cart

The problem:

i want dynamically reprice the cart without repricing the articles to offer the customers one or more discounts.

i also asked chatgpt, but the solutions were not great, and I got the tip using the add_fee method.

Here are 3 solutions i found and the side effects:

1.: Some solutions I found work only over the article price
prob: the user don't see that he have pay less

2.: add_fee Method with a negative number
prob: not recommend by Woo and case vat problems

3.: create a article with a negative value
prob: don't work with percent and if the discount is bigger than the cart there's also vat problems

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found after some research in the WOO Code and i hope its helps' someone.

discount_type can also: fixed_cart and reduce the cart only by value of cart.

For example: product €500, Coupon €1000 it get reduced only by €500 and the order can be done 4 free.

Woocomerce have a filter called "woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data" over this filter we can supply own coupons on the fly which are checked every times.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', 'create_discount_code', 10, 3);
            function create_discount_code($coupon_data, $code, $obj)
            {
            $cartValue = WC() && WC()->cart ? WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal() : 0;
                
                
                
                if ($code == "menge") {
                    
                    if ($cartValue > 1500) {
                        return array(
                            'code'          => 'menge',
                            'discount_type' => 'percent',
                            'amount'        => 30,
                        );
                    } else if ($cartValue > 1000) {
                        return array(
                            'code'          => 'menge',
                            'discount_type' => 'percent',
                            'amount'        => 20,
                        );
                    } else if ($cartValue > 500) {
                        return array(
                            'code'          => 'menge',
                            'discount_type' => 'percent',
                            'amount'        => 10,
                        );
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                }
            }

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_updated', 'update_cart_func' );
            function update_cart_func() {
                if ( !WC()->cart->has_discount( 'menge' )  && WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal() > 500) {
                    WC()->cart->apply_coupon( "menge" );
                }
                
            }
```